# how to pass ID in a link using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a book now button, when a user clicks on book now he should be redirected to a order confirmation page. I want to pass type and id in a url using jquery. 
want to pass this kind of url - http://localhost/company/order-confirmation?type=course&id=35

How can I do that in jquery.

html:

```
 <a href="" class="book_now" batch-id="">Book Now</a>
```

Jquery:

```
  $('.book_now',template).attr('batch-id', val['batch_id']);
```

Comment: `$('.book_now').attr('href', function(i, href) { return href + '&id=' + $(this).attr('batch-id'); });`

Comment: where should I add  http://localhost/company/order-confirmation

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `href` in an anchor dynamically like:

```
$('.book_now').attr('href', 'url link');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use data attribute for this task like

```
 <a href="" class="book_now" data-id="11">Book Now</a>
```

and in js code

```
var order_id= $('.book_now').data("id");
```

But why using  here if you want to send data over jquery, i think its better to use button here.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on this , its same what you want

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="/abc" class="book_now" batch-id="123">Book Now</a>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".book_now").click(function(e) {
  e.target.href += "?id=" + $(this).attr('batch-id');
})
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the attribute data* ([see this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)) because the attribute "batch-id" is no valid html.

In regular jQuery, if the link is provided like this:

```
<a href="http://localhost/company/order-confirmation?type=course" class="book_now" data-batch-id="123">Book Now</a>
```

i would do it like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '[data-batch-id]', function(e) {
       // Disable link behavior
       e.preventDefault();
       
       // Save information
       var batchID = $(this).data().batchId,
           href    = $(this).attr('href');
       
       // Check if any ID is aviable 
       if (batchID) {
          // Save the url and perform a page load
          var link = href + '&id=' + batchID;
          window.open(link, '_blank');
 
       } else {
          // Error handling
          alert('Can\'t find course, no ID provided')
       }
       
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://localhost/company/order-confirmation?type=course" class="book_now" data-batch-id="123">Book Now</a>
```